# JWPLAYER video hosting, streaming and pre rolled ads

Tags: video-streaming, jwplayer

I am having a requirement to upload videos on our website with the ability to run ads before any video is played. I am thinking to buy script of JWPLAYER enterprise edition, but I am not sure about the following things in which I need your suggestion -

1. When any video will be uploaded, will it be hosted on the server of the website or on the server of jwplayer?
2. Similarly how many videos will be streamed by JWPLAYER enterprise edition script?
3. The JWPLAYER enterprise edition will provide the functionality to apply pre rolled ads? I need that these ads should run before any video.

Please help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Mohit Tripathi

Comment: You need the ads edition of JW Player to do this. It is up to you if you want to host videos through us, or host your own videos.

Comment: Hi Ethan, I certainly want to upload it on your server (JWPLAYER) and also wants to stream it through your server too. I just want to know that if I purchase enterprise edition then will I get the functionality of pre rolled ads and if yes, then how?

Comment: You need to purchase a product from us called the JW Platform in order to do this, please reach out - http://www.jwplayer.com/contact-us/